# Multiple application android:name tags in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am using two libraries(SUGAR ORM and Instabug). They both require me to use the android:name tag of the application in my manifest. However, it seems you cannot have duplicates.Is there a way around this?

My manifest:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/runrouter_biggest"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
        //I need to declare a second android:name here>
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: you cannot ... you have to: create `class MyAppliction extends SugarApplication { }` and copy the code from `InstabugApplication` (or in oposite way) ... that's what extending Application(instead some static initializers) for such things are so bad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be out of luck. You can have only one instance of application class so you can specify only one `android:name` there.

However, you are actually not out of luck. Instabug does not require you to use their application class, [all they need is to call `Instanbug.initialize(...)...`](https://instabug.com/sdk-integration) which you can easily do in your application class derived from `SugarApp`:

```
class MyApplication extends SugarApp
{
    @Override
    void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Instabug.initialize(this)
            .setAnnotationActivityClass(InstabugAnnotationActivity.class)
            .setShowIntroDialog(true)
            .setEnableOverflowMenuItem(true);
    }
}
```

And define this application class in `android:name`.